# SQL Server 2008 Aggregation

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, max

Trying to figure out aggregation for table set below. For each change in Dept I want to sum Wages for that ID column. I also want to combine start and end times to one row per ID, dept.

What I am getting:

```
ID#    Dept   StartTime     EndTime    Wages
545    A        12:00        1:30       $50
545    A        1:30         3:00       $55
657    A        12:00        3:00       $100
657    B        3:00         6:00       $100
657    B        6:00         7:00       $50
```

What I want to look like:

```
ID#    Dept   StartTime     EndTime    Wages
545    A        12:00        3:00       $105
657    A        12:00        3:00       $100
657    B        3:00         7:00       $150
```

Comment: what if the times don't match exactly as they do in your sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is something like this (assuming your wages are saved as `int`)

```
SELECT ID, Dept, 
    MIN(StartTime) [StartTime],
    MAX(EndTime) [EndTime],
    SUM(Wages) [Wages]
FROM Table 
GROUP BY ID, Dept
```